# i want to matche some substring in my vector with regular expressions with R language

Tags: r, regex

i have vector that each element correspond to a gene.

here is my vector:

```
v = c("complement component 9 (C9), mRNA.", "dynein, axonemal, intermediate chain 2 (Dnaic2), mRNA.", " SH3 and PX domains 2B (Sh3pxd2b), mRNA.", "thiosulfate sulfurtransferase, mitochondrial (Tst), mRNA.", "peptidyl-tRNA hydrolase 2 (Ptrh2), transcript variant 2, mRNA.", "Meckel syndrome, type 1 (Mks1), mRNA.", "pleckstrin homology domain containing, family M (with RUN domain) member 1 (Plekhm1), mRNA.", "leucine rich repeat containing 59 (Lrrc59), mRNA.", "WD repeat containing, antisense to Trp53 (Wrap53), transcript variant 1, mRNA.", "glycerol-3-phosphate dehydrogenase 1 (soluble) (Gpd1), mRNA.")
```

i need to keep in a new dataframe that:

In the first column the names of symbole that appear inside brackets: for example in the first element of the vector the symbole is C9 (you can see in the substring "(C9)"), in the second  element the symboke is Dnaic2 (you can see in the substring "(Dnaic2)"), etc... .
Notes that you have to be careful because in some character strings of our vector there are streaks between corchet that do not correspond to the symbol, as for example in element 7 we have: "(with RUN domain)", or in the element 10 we have: "(soluble)".

In the second column of the dataframe, you must indicate the number of transcriptions of this symbol. let me explain: it may be that the same symbol reappears several times in our vector, and for that, the number of the transcription is indicated: "transcript variant 1", "transcript variant 2", etc ....
when the transcription number is not indicated, this means that there is only one transcription of this symbol.

in order to create my dataframe i have to use regular expressions

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `stringr` and `tidyr`:

```r
data.frame(column_1 = str_extract(v, "(?<=\\s\\()[^\\s]*?(?=\\),)"),
           column_2 = replace_na(str_extract(v, "(?<=transcript\\svariant\\s)\\d"), 1))
```

Comment: first at all thank you for your help.. i tried to run the function , but i have the follow error
"Error in str_extract(genes, "(?<=\\s\\()[^\\s]*?(?=\\),)") : 
  could not find function "str_extract"" . i have already installed the packages tidyr and stringr. How can i get ride of thir error pls ?

Comment: You need the packages `stringr` and `tidyr`. Install the package `tidyverse` to get them both (and several other useful packages).

Comment: thank you it works

Comment: i need to creat a new dataframe for wich each row corresponds to a unique symbol (symbols are in the first column of my new dataframe), and the number of times it appeared in the first dataframe (in the  second column of my new dataframe). I tried to make : "as.data.frame(table(df$column_1))" but i have this error :"Error in df$symbol : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Do you know what is the problem pls ?